# Sequence of complex numbers $\frac{\tan(in)}{n}$. Is it convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Consider the sequence of complex numbers 
$$z_n=
\frac{\tan(in)}{n}$$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Is it convergent or divergent?

Comment: What do you know about $\tan (in)$?

Comment: I cannot understand how to deal with it...

Comment: Do you know the definition?

Comment: No...do tell me

Comment: If you use $\tan = \frac{\sin}{\cos}$ and $\sin(ix) = i \sinh x = i\frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{2}$, $\cos(ix) = \cosh x = \frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$, what do you get?

Comment: I didn't know that sin(ix) and sinh x were the same thing -_-

Comment: OK fine now...but how am i supposed to check in a proper way that if it is convergent or not? Should I use the condition that Re(z) and Im(z) also converge??

Comment: If that is the case then z_n reduces to just a real sequence doesn't it? After I replace by e^x terms

Comment: Then you have $\tan(in)\to i$, so in particular -- taking the absolute value/modulus of your sequence, $\lvert \tan(in)/n\rvert\to?$ (Not that in my first comment, i had forgotten a $i$ in the relation between $\sin(ix)$ and $\sinh x$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
\tan(in)=\frac{\sin(in)}{\cos(in)}=i\frac{\sinh n}{\cosh n}=i\frac{e^{n}-e^{-n}}{e^{n}+e^{-n}}\stackrel{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow} i
$$
as $n\to+\infty$, we have that
$$
\frac{\tan(in)}{n}\stackrel{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\;\;.
$$

Comment: Thnx.. @ lot for this (y)